# User Input with Timer for Attendance

Tags: python, input, timer

Hi I'm just starting out in Python, I'd like to create a program which functions like an attendance. When the input receives a "present", it will add value to a list, but when the user fails to input anything within a period of time, nothing would be added to the list and then will proceed to another input again.

Here is where I'm at. I don't know why the timer doesn't stop after the condition, and why the final print always has all 3 values.

```
from threading import Timer
print(f"Class Attendance")
Class = ["Student 1  ", "Student 2  ", "Student 3  "]
Attendance = []
for s in Class:
    timeout = 5
    t = Timer(timeout, print, [f'Absent'])
    t.start()
    q = str(input(s))
    if q == "present" or "present po":
        Attendance.append(s)
        t.cancel
print(f"Present Students: {Attendance}")
```

Comment: You might want to review what Timer does and how you can use it. It will not interrupt the input. Also, the line *if q == "present" or "present po":* doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 1):

This might not necessarily be your desired answer, but it's hard to implement the `input()` function with timers because it's a blocking function. This means that input is required before the program can continue. However, other libraries offer non-blocking alternatives.

This solution should give you the desired outcome if you own a Windows computer.

First, `pip install msvcrt`

The msvcrt library detects keyboard inputs. While `msvcrt.getch()` will return one character, it is non-blocking, so the code below will work as you intend.

```
import msvcrt
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Class Attendance")
    students = ["Student 1", "Student 2", "Student 3"]
    attendance = []

    for stu in students:
        print(f"{stu}:", end=" ", flush=True)

        timeout = 5
        start_time = time.time()
        while time.time() - start_time < timeout: # timer
            if msvcrt.kbhit(): # non blocking
                if ord(msvcrt.getch()) == 112:  # p ascii value
                    attendance.append(stu)
                    print("present")
                    break
                else: # any other keystroke
                    print("absent")
                    break
        else: # if keyboard not hit
            print("absent")

    print(f"Present Students: {attendance}")
```

The code will detect whether the character p (for present) is pressed. If p is pressed, then the student is present. Likewise, the student is counted absent if another key besides lowercase p is pressed or no key is pressed after 5 seconds. I hope this was helpful.